# Select rows of pd.DataFrame where column values are "close" to each other

Tags: python, pandas

## Dataset

I have a movie dataset where there are over half a million rows, and this dataset looks like following (with made-up numbers)

```
MovieName  Date           Rating      Revenue
A          2019-01-15     3           3.4 million
B          2019-02-03     3           1.2 million
...        ...            ...         ...
```

## Object

Select movies that are released "closed enough" in terms of date (for example, the release date difference of movie A and movie B is less than a month) and see when the rating is same, how the revenue could be different.

## Question

I know I could write a double loop to achieve this goal. However, I am doubting this is the right/efficient way to do, because

- Some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476924/7784797) (see comment of @cs95 to the question) suggested iterating over a dataframe is "anti-pattern" and therefore something not advisable to do.
- The dataset has over half a million rows, I am not sure if writing double loop is something efficient to do.

Could someone provide pointers to the question I have? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show expected output and more sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is true that you should try avoiding loops when working with pandas. My idea is not ideal, but might point you in the right direction:

1. Retrieve month and year from the date column in every row to create new columns "month" and "year". You can see how to do it [here](https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi_code_snippets/extract_month_year_pandas)
2. Afterwards, group your dataframe by month and year (`grouped_df = df.groupby(by=["month","year])`) and the resulting groups are dataframe with movies from the same month and year. Now it's up to you what further analysis you want to perform, for example mean (`grouped_df = df.groupby(by=["month","year]).mean()`), standard deviation or something more fancy with the `apply()` function.

You can also [extract weeks](http://%60grouped_df%20=%20df.groupby(by=%5B%22month%22,%22year%5D)) if you want a period shorter than a month